# How do I get the total duration of a bunch of tiny video files in a folder?

Tags: windows-7

I have a bunch of small video files in a folder and I thought clicking on Properties of the folder would give me the total duration of all the video clips combined but it didn't.  What is the simplest way to count the total time of many different clips in a folder?  In the same folder I have some .srt files too.

Also, I use VLC player; is there a way to use it to solve my problem?  I don't have Windows Media Player.

Win 7.
IE 8.

Comment: How comfortable are you with scripting? This solution would work, but you would need to tweak it a bit to get the total: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987648/determine-running-times-of-videos-in-directory-using-powershell

Comment: If you select the items in the file browser, then in the bottom I can see the total length of the selected items.

Comment: @Bernhard should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: @EBGreen I can't script at all.

Comment: @Bernhard I tried this but I just get the total file size at the bottom!

Comment: @verve Which file format are the videos? I don't think Windows Explorer will show the length, if it can't natively read the files.

Comment: You can add the "length" column in explorer, if the length of time does not show up in that column for the file, it will not show in the bottom pane either.

Comment: @iglvzx FLV and MPEG-4.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the Windows Explorer Filter.

- Open the desired folder on Windows Explorer (WindowsKey-E);
- Click at the search bar (or use Ctrl-F);
- Type `System.Kind:=Video`;
- Select all video files from the result list;
- Open their properties (Right Mouse Button -> Properties);

The total duration calculation will be shown in the Details tab;

Comment: Thanks, man! : )

Answer (score 6):

As long as windows is able to read video metadata, right-clicking on them and going in Details does indeed show the total length. I just tested here on a combination of .MP4 and .WMV and it worked.

For windows to read video metadata properly, you may need to have Windows Media Player installed as well as appropriate codecs (using codec packs such as Shark007, K-Lite and CCCP is a good idea). Whether you can see thumbnails or not in Windows Explorer should give you an indication.

Other than that, you could use a media application that supports video and shows total time in playlists, such as Winamp.

Comment: My files are .FLV and MPEG-4 plus some .srt files scattered in the folder I'm trying to check.  Will it work on these?  Hmm...two of the video files have thumbnails but the rest are a single sheet of white.

Comment: No. Windows Explorer cannot read FLV metadata.

Comment: @verve I'm not sure about FLV. Maybe not as per iglvzx. As for SRT, they are subtitle files so there are no video or durations on those.

Answer (score 5):

Its very very simple. Just select all the videos. Put into VLC media player. Now click on the toggle playlist button. There you will see on top left just beside playlist total video playtime is shown.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to resize the hidden menu if you can't find one.
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=153989#wrap

Answer (score 4):

You can use Mpv (for Windows too).  Here I use it in Cygwin/Mingw:

```
mpv --term-playing-msg='SO_DURATION=${=duration}' --no-config --no-cache --quiet --frames=1 --vo=null --ao=null Selfie_del_futuro.ogv | grep ^SO_DURATION
SO_DURATION=45.053229
```

You can change SO_DURATION if you like, it is just a marker so that it can be grepped.

Comment: What's the stuff in the grey window?

Comment: Example usage of mplayer from a Bash prompt in the Cygwin terminal. Lines starting with "$" are commands and lines without "$" are output. The third line is there to show you that the command only outputs one line, which means you can easily parse and sum it with other durations.

Comment: It works in Linux as well. It collects the lengths. Then we can use e.g. a Python code to add those values if we deleted the part before the numbers:
`with open("lengths") as f: values = f.read().splitlines()`
`print(sum([float(v) for v in values])`

Answer (score 3):

If you select the items in the file browser, then in the bottom I can see the total length of the selected items.

As requested, here are some sample screenshots (from Windows 7).
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot to prove it

Comment: now try it with .flv files :)

Comment: Ha! I tried so many ways but turns out Windows Media Player is there to rescue! You can humiliate WMP all you want but it is dependable when needed ;)

Answer (score 2):

Install [this](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=97639&p=350143#p348096) extension in VLC. It works like a charm.

Comment: I think this is best for OP. If it works.

Comment: VLC can show the total playlist length without any extension. Maybe it couldn't do it in 2012 (when this answer was written), but it does it now.

Answer (score 1):

Select all files in question inside File Explorer.
Take a Right Click & Go to Properties.
In Properties Window, Take Details Tab.
Lookout for the value of Length and there it is!
Hope it works.
It sure works in Win 7 for Videos as I checked.

Comment: OP: "I have a bunch of small video files in a folder and I thought clicking on Properties of the folder would give me the total duration of all the video clips combined but it didn't"

Comment: The OP looked at the properties *of the folder.*  This answer is saying, "Go ***into*** the folder, and then ***select all the (video) files*** in the folder, and get their collected properties.  I can confirm (on my system) that what the OP tried, doesn't work, and this answer does.  YMMV.

Comment: Works on Windows 10!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffprobe` of the ffmpeg project. If you want to do it on the command line on a Linux or Mac OS X system (and maybe soon also Windows):

```
IFS='
'

for mf in *; do len=$(ffprobe $mf 2>&1 | grep Duration); echo "$len --- $mf"; done
```

You can even sort them by lenth:

```
for mf in *; do len=$(ffprobe $mf 2>&1 | grep Duration); echo "$len --- $mf"; done | sort
```

**Explanation:**

- The first command `IFS=` is for adjust shell globbing (ignore spaces in filenames).
- Then there is a `for`-loop over all files in the current directory (that is the `*`).
- Inside the `for`-loop a subshell `$(……)` is opened, where the `ffprobe` command is started, the output, which is normally going to STDERR is redirected (`2>`) to STDOUT (abbreviated with `&1`), then piped to `grep`, which searches and prints all lines containing the word *Duration*.
- The result of the subshell is saved into the variable `$len`.
- After the subshell the length and the name of the file is printed.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, see [this answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/can-i-find-the-total-play-duration-of-all-music/b34a810b-2c77-4491-a912-2a01cb4f3c27?auth=1).

You can select the audio files in a folder, then

1. look in the Details pane at the bottom of your Windows explorer window [switch this on in Organise, Layout, Details pane]
2. right-click, Properties, Details tab.

Both ways will show you the total length of the selected files.

If you want to include subfolders then you'll need to do a search on the top level folder of interest - search on type: mp3 or wma or whatever format you use and it will return all the corresponding files within that folder tree. Select them all in the search results window and then as I've written above.

If you have used a mixture of audio formats, you'll have to repeat the procedure for each type.